# How do I know what sound system is being used?

Tags: 10.04, sound, mythbuntu

I've noticed there is ALSA, OSS, and PULSEAUDIO. How do I know what I'm using?

(I'm running MythBuntu 10.04 and I want to figure out how to make all apps - VLC, Basero etc output via the SPDIF).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different applications can make use of different "sound systems".  For some applications, you can choose the sound backend at run time (e.g., via a preference setting); for other, this has to be a compile-time choice (therefore, it's up to the package maintainer to select one).

Applications that come in the main Ubuntu repository have been compiled with [PulseAudio](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/1/pulseaudio) support, so you can control the sound inputs and outputs via *System -> Preferences -> Sound* or [padevchooser](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/1/padevchooser).

Still, some applications do not support PulseAudio and only offer a choice of ALSA/OSS: older versions of Skype and Adobe Flash are the primary example, but also the free music player [Aqualung](http://aqualung.factorial.hu/).

So, in the end, the answer is: it's application-specific, and you might need to dig into the application preferences or upgrade/recompile to get them working the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

If your sound is working, right click on the Volume icon in the taskbar, and click preferences. The System you are using will be mentioned at the top.

PS: Thats how it happens in Ubuntu 9.04, which I am using now.